# cargo build: Should I keep the `target` dir after a compile for a historical audit log?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am using `cargo build` to build for many platforms.

Given a sha1 hash of one of the binaries I have released, I want to be able to tell exactly what input was used for the compiler (in case I need to reference it in a security audit).

I am using Docker to run `cargo build`, so I have hashes of each image that will be stored long term. The `target` dir can be many GB in size, so I do not want to be committing it to a Docker image if it is not needed.

I am not completely sure what data is contained in `target`.

Should I keep it, or is the `Cargo.lock` enough to understand what input was given to the compiler?

If a Cargo crate is deleted, is there an immutable reference I can always download (so no need to keep `target` which would contain the source code)?

Would running `cargo build` with verbose logs also be useful for a historical reference?

Answer (score 2):

It's much cheaper in terms of storage space to store the vendored dependencies instead of storing the target folder. The sources, being essentially text files, can be further compressed to reduce the final size.

The added benefit is that you can actually use those to perform a reproducible build and even if a crate disappears upstream, you will still have it.

Just run [`cargo vendor`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-vendor.html) and cargo will create a directory named `vendor` which will contain the sources of all your dependencies, including any transitive dependency. Then package those together with your app sources as a signed zip.

Comment: Do I have to use the `-s` flag to provide all the `Cargo.toml` files for the given workspace, and other local-only Rust crates too (these use path = x in the `Cargo.toml` `[dependencies]`)?

Comment: You don't have to use `-s` for the workspace.  I;m not sure about local crates, but I guess it won't be necessary. Just try it and check if the files are there